# Is it possible to cancel a call to speakTextAsync?

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the [javascript SDK of Microsoft Speech Synthesizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechsynthesizer) and calling `speakTextAsync` to convert text to speech.

This works perfectly, but sometimes the text is long and I want to be able to cancel in the middle, but I cannot find any way to do this. The documentation doesn't seem to indicate any way to cancel. The name `speakTextAsync` suggests that it returns a Task that could be cancelled, but in fact the method returns `undefined`, and I can't find any other way to do this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no way to stop it when it is speaking. But actually,as a workaround, you can just download the audio file and play the file yourself so that you can control everything. try the code below:

```
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.*;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.AudioConfig;

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class TextToSpeech {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String speechSubscriptionKey = "key";

            String serviceRegion = "location";

            String audioTempPath = "d://test.wav"; //temp file location

            SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(speechSubscriptionKey, serviceRegion);

          
            AudioConfig streamConfig = AudioConfig.fromWavFileOutput(audioTempPath);

            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, streamConfig);

            String filePath = "....//test2.txt"; // .txt file for test with long text
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            String text = Files.readString(path);
            synth.SpeakText(text);

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Speaker(audioTempPath));
            thread.start();

            System.out.println("play audio for 8s...");
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            System.out.println("stop play audio");
            thread.stop();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ex);

            assert (false);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}

class Speaker implements Runnable {

    private String path;

    public String getText(String path) {
        return this.path;
    }

    public Speaker(String path) {

        this.path = path;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            AudioInputStream stream;
            AudioFormat format;
            DataLine.Info info;
            Clip clip;

            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            format = stream.getFormat();
            info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(stream);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```